# Is it possible to update a hash key in amazon dynamo db?

Tags: database, amazon-dynamodb

I want to update hash key value in amazon dynamo db table. I also have a range key in the same table. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You cannot update the hash key value, you will have to delete and recreate the item.

Here is the relevant aws documentation 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValueUpdate.html